# exec: name not defined, but works earlier on in the same code

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib, python-exec

I ran into this when creating a script that exports dirs and mails to another account with exchangelib.

When I run code with "exec" it returns as not defined but earlier on in the same code it works.

This part doesn't work:

```
exec('a = van_account.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + '; b = a.all().only("id", "changekey"); data = van_account.export(b); up = naar_account.upload((naar_account.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + ', d) for d in data); print("[UPLOAD] %i mail geupload in %s" % (len(data), fol))')
```

This part is right above it and does work.
This also refers to "naar_account":

```
code = "create = Folder(parent=naar_account.inbox / "
par = ' '.join('"{}" /'.format(word) for word in par.split('/'))[:-1]

exec(code + par + ', name="%s"); create.save()' % fol)
```

This also works:

```
exec('print(naar_account)')
```

Even renaming it works and than it says the renamed part is not defined:

```
exec('wtf = naar_account; a = van_account.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + '; b = a.all().only("id", "changekey"); data = van_account.export(b); up = wtf.upload((wtf.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + ', d) for d in data); print("[UPLOAD] %i mail geupload in %s" % (len(data), fol))')
```

Full code:

```
def search_levels(van_account, naar_account):
    for subfolder in van_account.inbox.walk():
        subfolder = subfolder.absolute

        # If '/' means it has subfolders
        if '/' in subfolder.replace(van_account.inbox.absolute + '/', ''):
            # Strip fill path, leave only Inbox path
            par = subfolder.replace(van_account.inbox.absolute + '/', '')
            # Get last item, it's the Dir we need to create
            fol = par.split('/')[-1]
            # Replace last item, it's the Dir, we only need the parent
            par = par.replace(par.split('/')[-1], '')[:-1]

            code = "create = Folder(parent=naar_account.inbox / "
            par = ' '.join('"{}" /'.format(word) for word in par.split('/'))[:-1]

            exec(code + par + ', name="%s"); create.save()' % fol)
            print('[Created] %s' % fol)

            exec('print(naar_account)')

            exec('a = van_account.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + '; b = a.all().only("id", "changekey"); data = van_account.export(b); up = naar_account.upload((naar_account.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + ', d) for d in data); print("[UPLOAD] %i mail geupload in %s" % (len(data), fol))')

        else:
            par = None
            fol = subfolder.replace(van_account.inbox.absolute + '/', '')

            create = Folder(parent=naar_account.inbox, name=fol)
            create.save()
            print('[Created] %s' % fol)

            a =  van_account.inbox / fol
            b = a.all().only('id', 'changekey')
            data = van_account.export(b)
            up = naar_account.upload((naar_account.inbox / fol, d) for d in data)
            print('[UPLOAD] %i mail geupload naar %s' % (len(data), fol))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./migrate.py", line 225, in <module>
    start(van_adres, van_passwd, naar_adres, naar_passwd)
  File "./migrate.py", line 114, in start
    search_levels(van_account, naar_account)
  File "./migrate.py", line 154, in search_levels
    exec('a = van_account.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + '; b = a.all().only("id", "changekey"); data = van_account.export(b); wtf = naar_account; up = wtf.upload((wtf.inbox / ' + par + ' / ' + '"%s"' % fol + ', d) for d in data); print("[UPLOAD] %i mail geupload in %s" % (len(data), fol))')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/account.py", line 340, in upload
    is_empty, data = peek(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exchangelib/util.py", line 130, in peek
    first = next(iterable)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <genexpr>
NameError: name 'wtf' is not defined
```

Comment: Using `exec` this way causes serious security issues and as far as I can tell it is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Without further explanation why or how your comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: All of the code in the `exec` lines can be written directly in the program without parsing from a string as `exec` does. You are not sanitizing `par` and `fol`, so in effect there could be arbitrary code executed through these strings.

Answer (score 1):

`wtf` is used in the `exec`'s scope but seemingly nowhere else, with `exec` itself in a local scope. Therefore `wtf` will be a local variable in the `exec` scope. Modifications of the locals through `exec` are not visible outside of it, therefore `wtf` is not accessible from outside the `exec`'s scope at all.

Names in generator expressions (with the exception of the left-most `for` expression) are evaluated lazily when `__next__` is called. Therefore `wtf` from `wtf.inbox` will be looked up when `__next__` is called.

That happens in some other function outside the `exec` scope and therefore `wtf`, being local to the latter, is not found there.